# Send sms to Indian numbers using aws sns

Tags: php, sms, amazon-sns, aws-php-sdk

I am trying to send a sms to a particular number using aws sns using the following code but it requires a target/topic arn which is not applicable for me as I want to send sms to the numbers that I set in the params.

```
$client = SnsClient::factory([
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => "my key",
            'secret' => "my secret"
        ],
        'region'  => "us-east-1",
        'version' => "latest"
    ]);

    $sent = $client->publish(
        [

            'Message' => 'This is the message',
            'PhoneNumber' => '+91887******7'
        ]
    );
```

I am not able to find the exact params for the publish object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to update the aws php sdk ([1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/download/aws.phar)). Then the following code works fine -

```
$sns = SnsClient::factory(array(
        'credentials' => array(
            'key' => 's3_key',
            'secret' => 's3_secret'
        ),
        'region' => Constants::$s3Region,
        'version' => 'latest'
    ));

$msgattributes = [
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
            'DataType' => 'String',
            'StringValue' => 'Klassroom',
        ],
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType' => [
            'DataType' => 'String',
            'StringValue' => 'Transactional',
        ]
    ];

    $payload = array(
        'Message' => $message,
        'PhoneNumber' => $number,
        'MessageAttributes' => $msgattributes
    );

    $result=$sns->publish($payload);
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [Amazon SNS `Publish()` documentation for PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sns-2010-03-31.html#publish):

- **TargetArn:** If you don't specify a value for the `TargetArn` parameter, you must specify a value for the `PhoneNumber` or `TopicArn` parameters.
- **TopicArn:** If you don't specify a value for the `TopicArn` parameter, you must specify a value for the `PhoneNumber` or `TargetArn` parameters.
- **PhoneNumber:** If you don't specify a value for the `PhoneNumber` parameter, you must specify a value for the `TargetArn` or `TopicArn` parameters.

Therefore, provide a `PhoneNumber` instead of a Target/Topic.